# Components of vector

Tags: vectors

In the notation:

```
Vector(v) = ai + bj + ck
```

Aren't a, b, c the components of vector? I looked on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_notation#Unit_vector_notation) which says they "are the magnitudes of the components of v."

Does it mean the same?

If not then how can I convert the components of vector given in set notation:

$v = (c_x, c_y, c_z)$.

Where, $c_x, c_y, c_z$ are the components into the $i, j, k$ notation?

Comment: After a small amount of Googling I've seen that some people refer to $a$, $b$, and $c$ as the components of $\mathbf v$ (wrt the standard basis) and some people refer to $a\mathbf i$, $b\mathbf j$, and $c\mathbf k$ as the components.  Wikipedia obviously takes the second meaning and thus the magnitude of each of those components is $|a|$, $|b|$, and $|c|$ respectively.

Comment: For Wikipedia (and many people), the componets are the vectors $a \mathbf i$, $b\mathbf j$ and $c\mathbf k$. $a,b,c$ are its coordinates.

Comment: If I have components given: $c_x, c_y, c_z$ how can I convert it into $i, j, k$ notation?

Comment: In $\Bbb R^3$ the standard basis $\{\mathbf i, \mathbf j, \mathbf k\}$ is defined by $\mathbf i=(1,0,0)$, $\mathbf j = (0,1,0)$, and $\mathbf k=(0,0,1)$.  Thus $v=(c_x, c_y,c_z) = c_x\mathbf i + c_y\mathbf j + c_z\mathbf k$.

Comment: So, if I have a vector $AB$, $A = (2,3)$ and $B (7, 6)$ then components will be $(7-2, 6-3) = (5, 3)$ then I can simply write it in $i, j, k$ notation: $5i + 3j + 0k$ right?

Comment: $\mathbf k$ doesn't exist in $\Bbb R^2$ so you'd just write it as $5\mathbf i + 3\mathbf j$.  On the other hand, if $A$ and $B$ are the points $A(2,3,0)$ and $B(7,6,0)$, then $(\vec {AB})_{\mathcal E}$ does equal $5\mathbf i + 3\mathbf j + 0\mathbf k$. Though even then the $0\mathbf k$ is usually left off because it's just the zero vector.

Comment: For more information about vectors, I've (as well as many, many others) written several answers here that might help you understand these concepts a little better.  Two that I'll single out are [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283988/what-are-the-building-blocks-of-a-vector/1284005#1284005) and [this one](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1395970/what-is-the-logic-rationale-behind-the-vector-cross-product/1471129#1471129).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a vector $\mathbf v \in V$ where $V$ is a $3$-dimensional real vector space.  There is a theorem which tells us that every vector space has at least one basis.  That allows us to say there exists a basis $S=\{\mathbf s_1, \mathbf s_2, \mathbf s_3\}$ of $V$.  By the definition of a basis, we can write $\mathbf v$ as a linear combination of $S$:

$$\mathbf v = v_1\mathbf s_1 + v_2\mathbf s_2 + v_3\mathbf s_3$$

After choosing a basis for $V$ we can make use of another very useful theorem in linear algebra: every $n$-dimensional real vector space is isomorphic to $\Bbb R^n$, where $\Bbb R^n$ is the space of all ordered "tuples" of real numbers: for instance $\Bbb R^3 = \{(a,b,c) \mid a,b,c \in \Bbb R\}$.  What that means for us is that we can freely convert any vectors in our abstract real vector space $V$ to vectors in $\Bbb R^3$ and vice versa.  The "natural" way to do so is $$\mathbf v = v_1\mathbf s_1 + v_2\mathbf s_2 + v_3\mathbf s_3 \leftrightarrow (v_1, v_2, v_3) = (\mathbf v)_S$$

The fact that $V$ and $\Bbb R^3$ are isomorphic as vector spaces means that if we'd like to perform a linear transformation $T$ of a vector $\mathbf v\in V$ we can instead first convert $\mathbf v \to (\mathbf v)_S$, perform the transformation in $\Bbb R^3$, and then convert back $T((\mathbf v)_S) \to T(\mathbf v)$.  Either way we'll get the same answer.

Here's an example: let $\mathbf v= 2\mathbf s_1 + 3\mathbf s_3$ and $\mathbf w=\mathbf s_1 -2\mathbf s_2 + \mathbf s_3$.  Consider the linear transformation $T(\mathbf x) = 2\mathbf x + \mathbf w$.  Then $$\begin{align}T(\mathbf v) &= 2\mathbf v + \mathbf w \\ &= 2(2\mathbf s_1 + 3\mathbf s_3) + (\mathbf s_1 -2\mathbf s_2 + \mathbf s_3) \\ &= (4+1)\mathbf s_1 +(0-2)\mathbf s_2 + (6+1)\mathbf s_3 \\ &= 5\mathbf s_1 -2\mathbf s_2 + 7\mathbf s_3\end{align}$$
vs
$$\begin{align}T(\mathbf v) \rightarrow T([\mathbf v]_S) &= 2(\mathbf v)_S + (\mathbf w)_S \\ &= 2(2,0,3) + (1,-2,1) \\ &= (4+1,0-2,6+1) \\ &= (5,-2,7) \\ &\rightarrow 5\mathbf s_1 -2\mathbf s_2 + 7\mathbf s_3\end{align}$$

*Note*: Technically $T: V\to V$ and $T:\Bbb R^3\to \Bbb R^3$ are different transformations -- and thus should probably have different names -- but usually we're not that observant.

As for the nomenclature, apparently some people use the term "components of a vector $\mathbf v$ (with respect to $S$)" to mean the scalars $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ whereas others call the components $v_1\mathbf s_1$, $v_2\mathbf s_2$, and $v_3\mathbf s_3$ -- distinguishing $v_1$, $v_2$, and $v_3$ as the *coordinates* of $\mathbf v$.

And for the notation, for historical reasons (look up the quaternions for more info) the "standard" basis of $\Bbb R^3$ is often labeled $\mathcal E = \{\mathbf i, \mathbf j, \mathbf k\}$ where $\mathbf i=(1,0,0)$, $\mathbf j = (0,1,0)$, and $\mathbf k= (0,0,1)$ by definition.

Thus $$(\mathbf v)_S = (v_1, v_2, v_3) = v_1\mathbf i + v_2\mathbf j + v_3\mathbf k$$