# Find a matrix $A$ so that $[T(\vec{v})]_B = A[\vec{v}]_B$

Tags: linear-algebra

> Let $A = \begin{bmatrix}-1&4\\-2&3\end{bmatrix}, \vec{b}_1 = \begin{bmatrix}3\\2\end{bmatrix}, \vec{b}_2 = \begin{bmatrix}-1\\1\end{bmatrix},$ and $B = \{\vec{b}_1, \vec{b}_2\}.$ Find a matrix $A$ so that $[T(\vec{v})]_B = A[\vec{v}]_B$

I don't know the symbol for the B they are writing but I'm not sure if it matters. I don't even understand what this question is even asking me to solve. B equals some set of those two vectors? What is T(v) and A(v) and what does it mean $_B$ If anyone could even point me to a question that's smiliar but with different numbers im sure i can figure it out

Comment: You already give a matrix $A$, but no linear transformation $T$.

Comment: So should I multiply A by the two given vectors or?

Comment: Can you link me to a similar problem so I can see the method of solving this @Aweygan

Comment: You need a matrix $A'$. The matrix $A$ is the standard matrix of $T$. $B$ stands for basis, and they're asking for the matrix of $T$ with respect to the basis $B$. Look in your textbook for the change-of-basis formula.

Comment: Found this: https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/alternate-bases/change-of-basis/v/linear-algebra-change-of-basis-matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just clarify the question for you.

$\mathcal B$ is a basis (thus why they named it $\mathcal B$ ;) ) and the notation $[v]_{\mathcal B}$ and $[T(v)]_{\mathcal B}$ denote the matrix representations (i.e. column matrix containing the coordinates) of the vectors $v$ and $T(v)$ respectively ($T$ is a linear transformation so $T(v)$ is a vector) wrt $\mathcal B$.  They want you to express the linear transformation $T$ as a matrix whose domain and codomain are given wrt the basis $\mathcal B$.

Now, unfortunately this question is written poorly because $1)$ instead of writing a prescription for $T$ they give a matrix $A$ and $2)$ the $A$ in the first sentence is different than the one in the second.  But we can infer what they mean from the context: the $A$ in the first sentence is the matrix representation for $T$ **in the standard basis** and you need to find *another* matrix (which they *also call $A$* because whoever wrote this question is a terrible person) which represents $T$ but this time wrt $\mathcal B$.

Comment: So do I need to multiply vector $b_1, b_2$ to $A$ ?

Comment: Do you know what is meant by "the matrix representation of a linear transformation (or vector)"?

Comment: I think I should first diagonlize $A$

Comment: If you want, but it's an unnecessary step.

Comment: What is meant by ""the matrix representation of a linear transformation (or vector)"

Comment: oh yeah i know what that is

Comment: [This answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1283988/what-are-the-building-blocks-of-a-vector/1284005#1284005) will hopefully explain what the matrix representation of a vector is.  Then given a linear map $T$ and a vector $v$, the matrix representation of $T$ with respect to (wrt) a basis $\mathcal B$ is the matrix $M$ such that $M[v]_{\mathcal B} = [T(v)]_{\mathcal B}$.  And [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460141/on-the-change-of-coordinates-of-a-matrix) will hopefully help you understand change of basis of a matrix.

Comment: I got $P^{-1}AP = \begin{bmatrix}5&10\\-10&5\end{bmatrix}$, @Bye_World, can you explain to me why in the book in the solution they are multiplying this matrix by $\frac{1}{5}$?

Comment: @Yusha [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=matrix+multiplication+%7B%7B3,-1%7D,%7B2,1%7D%7D%5E(-1)*%7B%7B-1,4%7D,%7B-2,3%7D%7D*%7B%7B3,-1%7D,%7B2,1%7D%7D) also gets $\frac 15$ of that matrix, so I guess you made a mistake somewhere in your calculations.  Try to go back through and see where you made a mistake.  If you can't find it then ask a new question *with the work you've done* and someone will probably be able to spot the error for you.